# Is a function with an empty domain and an empty range bijective?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

According to the definition of a function, for all $x$ in domain, there is a $y$ in range such that $y = f(x)$. Therefore, if the domain and range are both empty, the conditions for a function are met by vacuity.

Let $F: A \rightarrow A$ and $A=\emptyset$.

For all $a,a'\in A$, $F(a) = F(a') \implies a=a'$ by vacuity. Thus F is injective.

"For all $F(a) \in A$, $\exists a \in A$ such that $a = F(a)$" is also true by vacuity. Thus F is injective.

Because F is both injective and surjective, F is bijective. Is this correct?

Edit: and also, is it correct to say that a function with an empty domain and a nonempty range is injective but not surjective?

Comment: Is this a question?

Comment: yes, are my statements correct?

Comment: Yes,  both are correct.  The empty function is a bijection on the empty domain to itself, and is an injection on the empty set to any other set.

Comment: It is worth pointing out that this is one of the (*several*) reasons why algebraists and combinatorists like to define $0^0=1$, as for finite nonempty sets $A,B$ the number of general functions with domain $A$ and codomain $B$ can be found to be $|B|^{|A|}$.  Allowing $A$ and/or $B$ to be empty as well and letting $0^0=1$ the identity continues to be true.  Similarly, for bijective functions we have $n!$ bijective functions on a set with $n$ elements, noting that we define $0!=1$, again in reference to the existence of the one bijective function with both empty domain and empty codomain.